# HTML Embedded video cut off

Tags: html, youtube, width

I am trying to embed a video from YouTube into my site. I am wondering if there is a way to relate the width and height based on the window size. For example, on an iPhone it looks something like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgRnV.png). Can I make the video shrink in width to smaller than the display size? Can I tie in my responsive site somehow, to get that?

It works great on computers or other larger screened devices, but not mobile.

Source:

```
<center><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/zRDi1DT3AFA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>
```

[Full page source](https://jsfiddle.net/cuj8k9ex/)

Thanks for the help!

[edit: source]

Comment: I think there is some fiddling with CSS you can do to set connect minimum screen size to size of elements.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to embed Youtube videos responsive by overriding the Youtube style (CSS).

Add the following CSS:

```
.video-con {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px; 
    height: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-con iframe,
.video-con object,
.video-con embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And then wrap the `iframe` with `div`:

```
<div class="video-con">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/zRDi1DT3AFA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```